# How to find overlapping percentage of two polyline stored in mongodb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, geojson, google-polyline

I am using google maps API to get directions from one place to another. Google maps returns a polyline that looks something like this

```
o`kpBywaaMQs@y@{Ag@LUJEKUsFyATeE|@i@@{B?w@@iBLkC\}APoBP{BPyAJuBCqAJeAHkAB{@Bs@JcAVyCv@yBlBl@i@JoAPuB?}@@UB]NWRq@^yBdAaB~@IBEr@MpBK~A@RDLLFxBf@hAVb@P`Bz@bErB
```

### First query

**I want to know if I store this polyline in the mongo database or do I convert it to a list of points and store it as a `LineString`?**

Converting the polyline to points returns something like this

```
[
 (18.5756, 73.74221),
 (18.57569, 73.74247),
 (18.57598, 73.74239),
 (18.57601, 73.74237),
 (18.57603, 73.74238),
 (18.57605, 73.7424),
 (18.57622, 73.74286),
 (18.57642, 73.74279),
 (18.57653, 73.74273),
 (18.57656, 73.74279),
 (18.57667, 73.74401),
 (18.57712, 73.7439),
 (18.57811, 73.74359),
 (18.57832, 73.74358),
]
```

### Second question

I will have to work with multiple such polylines and I need to find if two or more polylines overlap each other (and by what percentage if possible).

This relates to the first question as I would assume that executing a query for my above requirement would need the polyline to be stored in one of the two formats for eaiser (or successful) query execution.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to store it has a GeoJSON object, if you want to use the geospatial queries of mongodb. `LineString` seems indeed the best for you here

You can check if two GeoJSON object overlap each other with [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#geointersects)
Or you can check if an object is inside another with [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/)

But it doesn't seems that you can have the percentage.